# JSON parsing multiple nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, talend

[image]

I am trying to parse below json, which has multiple nested lists (input & output), how do I parse it ?

```
{
  "status":"current",
  "entry":[{
      "item":{
        "name":"Task1",
        "identifier":"T00001",
        "input":[{
            "type":{
              "text":"InputTask1-1"
            },
            "valueString":"Weekly"
          },
          {
            "type":{
              "text":"InputTask1-2"
            },
            "valueString":"Daily"
          }
        ],
        "output":[{
            "type":{
              "text":"OutputTask1-1"
            },
            "valueString":"Daily"
          },
          {
            "type":{
              "text":"OutputTask1-2"
            },
            "valueString":"Weekly"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "item":{
        "name":"Task2",
        "identifier":"T00002",
        "input":[{
            "type":{
              "text":"InputTask2-1"
            },
            "valueString":"Weekly"
          },
          {
            "type":{
              "text":"InputTask2-2"
            },
            "valueString":"Daily"
          }
        ],
        "output":[{
            "type":{
              "text":"OutputTask2-1"
            },
            "valueString":"Daily"
          },
          {
            "type":{
              "text":"OutputTask2-2"
            },
            "valueString":"Weekly"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking for delimited output file like this:

```
"TaskName"|"TaskId"|"InputName"|"InputValue"|"OutputName"|"OutputValue"
Task1|T00001|InputTask1-1|Weekly|outputDummyText|outputDummyValue
Task1|T00001|InputTask1-2|Daily|outputDummyText|outputDummyValue
Task1|T00001|inputDummyText|inputDummyValue|OutputTask1-1|Daily
Task1|T00001|inputDummyText|inputDummyValue|OutputTask1-2|Weekly
Task2|T00002|InputTask2-1|Weekly|outputDummyText|outputDummyValue
Task2|T00002|InputTask2-2|Daily|outputDummyText|outputDummyValue
Task2|T00002|inputDummyText|inputDummyValue|OutputTask2-1|Daily
Task2|T00002|inputDummyText|inputDummyValue|OutputTask2-2|Weekly
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library.

Define your model:

```
data class MyData(val status: String, val entry: List<Entry.ItemContainer>) {

    data class Entry(val itemContainer: List<ItemContainer>) {

        data class ItemContainer(val item: Item) {

            data class Item(
                val name: String,
                val identifier: String,
                val input: List<TypeContainer>,
                val output: List<TypeContainer>
            ) {

                data class TypeContainer(val valueString: String, val type: Type) {

                    data class Type(val text: String)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Read json string from file:

```
val json = File("data.json").readText()
```

Map the data to the defined model using Gson:

```
val myData = Gson().fromJson<MyData>(json, MyData::class.java)
```

Print the result in desired format (or save it to file):

```
println("\"TaskName\"|\"TaskId\"|\"InputName\"|\"InputValue\"|\"OutputName\"|\"OutputValue\"")

for (itemContainer: MyData.Entry.ItemContainer in myData.entry) {
    with(itemContainer.item) {
        for (typeContainer in input) {
            println("$name|$identifier|${typeContainer.type.text}|${typeContainer.valueString}|outputDummyText|outputDummyValue")
        }

        for (typeContainer in output) {
            println("$name|$identifier|inputDummyText|inputDummyValue|${typeContainer.type.text}|${typeContainer.valueString}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
      JSONObject jsonParent = new JSONObject(response);
      JSONArray jsonarray = jsonParent .getJSONArray("entry");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject c = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        
          JSONObject jsonItem = c.getString("item");
        
          JSONArray inputItemArray = jsonItem.getJSONArray("input");
        
            for (int j = 0; j < inputItemArray.length(); j++) {
              JSONObject inputItemObj = inputItemArray .getJSONObject(j);
              String invalueString = inputItemObj.getSting("valueString ");
            }
        
          JSONArray outputItemArray = jsonItem.getJSONArray("output");
        
          for (int k = 0; k < outputItemArray.length(); k++) {
            JSONObject outputItemObj = outputItemArray.getJSONObject(K);
            String outvalueString = outputItemObj.getSting("valueString ");
          }
        }
```